# PowerQuery syntax to overcome #NUM! error

Tags: powerquery

I have two columns of data in Excel. Using PowerQuery I am trying to divide these two columns and call it column X. The problem is that there are zeros in these two columns meaning that we get a "#NUM!" in Column X when dividing. How can I write an IF statement in PowerQuery so that IF the value of column X (the division) is Nan (#NUM!) then it is set to zero?

The below doesn't change the NaN's to zeros:

if[Column1]/[Column2]="NaN" then 0 else[Column1]/[Column2]

Comment: How about doing calculation then right-click column and replace errors with a null

Comment: Tried that already but this doesn't remove the #NUM! error.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a FAQ but approach is similar in almost every langage.  I'd write your statement like this: if [Column2] = 0 then 0 else [column1]/[column2].  Should work for all non-zero denominators.

Other thought, I just used this:  Powerquery (and PowerPivot) has a divide function that is divide-by-zero-safe! divide(column1,column2).  Shorter to write and should perform better as it is only performing the calculation once.  Especially with more complex denominators.

Final thought: because they aren't additive, I tend not to store ratios in the PQ results choosing instead to calculate dynamically in powerpivot or elsewhere in the reporting.  In Excel you can use =iferror(a/b, 0).

JR